# FPGA clock only positive lag?

Tags: fpga, clock, clock-speed

I have an FPGA with the following, simple clock divider, written in VHDL:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
 
entity main is
    Port(
        Clk : in std_logic;
        output : out std_logic
    );
end main;
 
architecture Behavioral of main is
    signal sig_counter : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal sig_output : std_logic := '0';
begin
    process(Clk) is
    begin   
        if rising_edge(Clk) then
            if sig_counter = "1111100" then
                sig_counter <= (others => '0');
                sig_output <= not sig_output;
            else
                sig_counter <= sig_counter + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
        output <= sig_output;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

However, when measuring in my logic analyzer, I see that after a couple of pulses, say 20 or so, I have an increased total time compared to what I do expect.
An example I have provided in this screenshot:
[image: Logic Analyzer screenshot]

As you can see, the pulses should have a period of exactly 5us (my FPGA is clocked at 50MHz). For one pulse (B1-B2), this is true. But when you see me taking multiple pulses (A1-A2) you see that 2 clock pulses have been added into the timing. No matter where I check this, it is always a few clock pulses more than I would expect.

- Could this be clock differences between the LA and FPGA? I wouldn't think that could lead to more than 10ns in difference?
- Is there something off in my code? since every pulse that I measure separately is 10us
- Is the clock not ideal? (ofcourse not, but than I would assume average of 0 delay over a large amount of samples?)
- Am I missing some key concept here that I did not take into account?

The FPGA that I am using is one on the development board nexys2 from Xilinx.
I am not that experienced in this field, so let me know what I can provide more in terms of info or screenshots to help me getting some useful feedback.

Comment: What was the sampling frequency of the analyzer? It just could happen that because fpga/LA clocks are asynchronous, the moment when LA sampled the "bad" point was just after the fpga signal change, and was reported on the next LA clock.

Comment: 100 MHz, but the deal is that whenever I check, I will always see the same behaviour. Which I wouln't expect for "random" mishaps. Or am I misunderstanding your point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clocks are not ideal, and they're more likely to be systematically biased than randomly biased every time you try an experiment. It is quite likely that one of the "50MHz" clock or the logic analyser is running slightly faster.

Your overall system design will have to take this into account.

I'm guessing the clock is driven by a PLL from a crystal on board the FPGA dev board? In which case it is probably temperature sensitive. It may be sensitive enough to change visibly if you heat up / cool down the board, which is a fun little experiment.

If you have *two* clock dividers, or you can route the 50MHz source clock into the LA, you should see that they stay a constant number of pulses in sync with each other, even if the time does not precisely agree with the LA.